# How to get all the TOP rows that are equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I am trying to write a query to answer the question "What Pop Tart flavor is sold in the most stores?"
Here is my schema:

[image]

I have this attempt:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountOfStores, PTF.PopTartFlavor AS PopTartFlavor
FROM tKrogerStore_PopTartFlavor KSPTF
INNER JOIN tPopTartFlavor PTF
ON KSPTF.PopTartFlavorID = PTF.PopTartFlavorID
GROUP BY PTF.PopTartFlavor
ORDER BY CountOfStores DESC
```

but the query gives me this:

[image]

and I just want the first 2 rows because they both have a count of 2, but if I say TOP 1 I just get the first row with a count of 2 and I don't get both rows that have a count of 2. How do I get both rows that have the same count (2)?

Comment: Please don't use images for code, table definitions or data. Use formatted text.

Comment: Use an inner query to find the top  value and then select all stores that have that value; just a thought.

Comment: @DaleK Just curious: 1. how can I communicate the schema without snipping it? 2. The query results are for illustration and wouldn't need to be debugged: why can't that be pasted?

Comment: You communicate the schema using by scripting the create table. Images are so much harder to read easily, especially when taking into account responsive devices. It also breaks the flow on the eye. [More](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try uisng having the count(*) = to the max result

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountOfStores, PTF.PopTartFlavor AS PopTartFlavor
    FROM tKrogerStore_PopTartFlavor KSPTF
    INNER JOIN tPopTartFlavor PTF
    ON KSPTF.PopTartFlavorID = PTF.PopTartFlavorID
    GROUP BY PTF.PopTartFlavor
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    select max(CountOfStores)
    from (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountOfStores, PTF.PopTartFlavor AS PopTartFlavor
        FROM tKrogerStore_PopTartFlavor KSPTF
        INNER JOIN tPopTartFlavor PTF
        ON KSPTF.PopTartFlavorID = PTF.PopTartFlavorID
        GROUP BY PTF.PopTartFlavor
    ) t
)
```

Comment: Awesome. I pasted it into SSMS and it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @nicomp  thanks  ..  hope  one of answer is rate as right ..

Answer (score 1):

I would capture the binned count and the overall max count in the same subquery query (the latter using an aggregated windowed function), then in the outer query filter for when they're equal.

```
select      CountOfStores, PopTartFlavor
from        (
                select      CountOfStores = count(*),
                            maxCountOfStores = max(count(*)) over(), 
                            PTF.PopTartFlavor
                from        @tKrogerStore_PopTartFlavor KSPTF
                join        @tPopTartFlavor PTF ON KSPTF.PopTartFlavorID = PTF.PopTartFlavorID
                group by    PTF.PopTartFlavor
            ) c 
where       countOfStores = maxCountOfStores
```